# Transferring data from Pi to Pi?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+

I have two Raspberry Pi's one of them is connected to a ThingsBoard platform
and was working just fine, I tried to copy the Python code from the SD card to a new one, then I started the Pi but it didn't work. Even though Raspbian is installed on the SD card.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what your issue here is. That's at least partially due to the fact that your question misses some essential punctuation. Please format your question; add a dot at the end of a sentence, etc.

Comment: How do you run the python code on the old Pi or does it auto start somehow?

Comment: I think you need to give a better clue as to what "Thingsboard" is and how you got it running on your RPi. If you have a new 3B+ or 3A+ you need to be running an OS that was created after the release date for your new hardware or it won't boot.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please try to add more details to make your question answerable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the two RPi's on the network?  If so, it's a simple matter of using SCP from one to the other.

Assuming you are logged-on to the RPi("A"), and you are in the same directory as the file("filename") you want to transfer to the other RPi("B").

For this example, let's assume you want to transfer the file to the directory "/home/pi/".  We'll also assume you are using the username "pi" on both machines:

```
scp ./filename pi@ip-address-for-B:/home/pi
```

This could copy "filename" to your other RPi.